# A gotcha of using .NET collections (ArrayList, List,..) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I just realized this and I've learned it the hard way, so I want to share. Consider you have the following list of strings:

```
>$list = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
>$list.Add("x")
>$list.Add("yy")
>$list.Add("zzz")
>$list
x
yy
zzz
```

Now if you want to get the number of items in the list, you would access the .Count property, and it gives you "3" as expected.

```
>$list.Count
3
```

However, sometimes you would make mistake by accessing .Length instead of .Count. In other languages, like Python or C#, you would get an error saying this property is not available. But in PowerShell, it turns out that, if it's not found on that object, it iterates through the contained objects and access the property on them. So you end up having a list of Lengthes! Surprise!!

```
>$list.Length
1
2
3
```

You can even invoke methods!

```
>$list.ToUpper()
X
YY
ZZZ
```

Note that, as I've tried, this "feature" also works for System.Collections.ArrayList. But it does not work for PowerShell's builtin array type.

What is this "feature" called? And why is it designed such way? It's very surprising and error-prone.

Comment: It has been called many things.  Member enumeration is the latest IIRC.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx

Comment: I don't like this new "feature" (introduced in PSv3) -- it makes your script backwards incompatible with PSv2... :( I really don't think the  slightly reduced number of characters justifies breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Andy, I'am getting old, so I somewhere share your opinion, but if some new scripts won't run in PowerShell V2.0, Whatever happens old scripts wich were really working in PowerShell V2.0 will work in PowerShell V3.0. As usual in computer equipment you need to stick to the older technologie, this should not stop technologie to progress.

Comment: @JPBlanc, I just don't think breaking backwards compatibility was really worth it in this case. This actually happened to me the other day -- developed my script in the PSv3 ISE (awesome) to deploy to a system with PSv2 and ended up having to figure out why there was no member named "..." on my object. IIRC intellisense just gave it to me so I went with it.

Comment: It appends to me too !

Comment: @AndyArismendi This wouldn't be the only breaking change in V3 (foreach handling of $null, RootModule in psd1, early pipeline termination, DLR, etc).   You can always start up PowerShell v2 that comes with V3 to test your scripts under v2.  What was more surprising to me was that we didn't get a .ps3 file extension out of this.  FWIW, breaking changes aside, I **love** this new feature.  Walking XML (and nested collections in general) is a whole lot easier IMO.

Comment: Personally, I'd re-write this question and your answer to be a bit more suitable to the site.  Currently, the question contains the information that I actually want to know and the answer is of no interest to me (except for the link to more info).

Comment: @Keith, I'm not saying its a bad feature. It'snice to use less code to accomplish the same thing. `$collection.property` is nicer than `$collection | % {$_.property}`. Though I do find it a little strange since the property doesn't technically exist on the collection object. Handling of $null in foreach is great btw, I always though it was ridiculous i had to do `foreach ($foo in $bar) { if ($foo) {...`... I looked to see if I could run the PS3 ISE in 2.0 mode like the shell which would be nice if it limited the intellisense to only whats available in 2.0 but that doesn't exist unfortunately.

Comment: It's breaking change in case you use export and import from/to clixml. Try this and compare results: `$a = [pscustomobject]@{Prop = @($null, $null) }; $a.Prop.Length;
$a | Export-Clixml D:\temp\test.clixml;
$b = Import-Clixml D:\temp\test.clixml;
$b.Prop.Length` Sorry for the formatting.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keith Hill mentioned in the comment that this is a new feature called Member Enumeration in V3.

Refer to "[*New V3 Language Features*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/)" on devblogs.microsoft.com.

Comment: To follow-up on @SteveKaye 's comment, I'll at least add the "why" from the excellent link, above. `"We added this feature to make it easier to deal with commands that return one or many objects.  Experienced PowerShell scripters knew they needed to use @() to handle that situation correctly, but we really thought that was less than perfect... We are not aware of any scripts where this change broke a script, but did not expose an underlying problem in the script."` Interesting feature.